# Correct use of Bootstrap Grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am learning to use BootStrap, and I really love the idea of it.
However, I have stumbled across an issue I can not figure how to solve.
(I did try to search for an answer, tried some versions - non worked).

That should actually not be that hard, so I am frustrated. So here it is.

I have three blocks, which I want to go to nice **new** rows, when screen size reduces. But its not. Here is the code:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 54px;">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="about-why-texts">
            <img src="img/icon-check.png" />
            <div>Telegram deposit system</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="about-why-texts">
            <img src="img/icon-check.png" />
            <div>Safe and secured website</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="about-why-texts">
            <img src="img/icon-check.png" />
            <div>Automated withdrawal system</div>
        </div>
    </div>                                  
</div>
```

Now when reducing the screen width, they stay the same **like 1000ton stone**. I want them to move in 3 new rows, when screen gets reduced.

Can anyone please teach me what I am doing wrong, and how can I fix it.

Huge Thanks, Marek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.border{
  border:thin black solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row text-center" style="padding-top: 54px;">
                                <div class="col-md-4  col-xs-12 border">
                                    <div class="about-why-texts">
                                        <img src="img/icon-check.png" />
                                        <div>Telegram deposit system</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4  col-xs-12 border">
                                    <div class="about-why-texts">
                                        <img src="img/icon-check.png" />
                                        <div>Safe and secured website</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4  col-xs-12 border">
                                    <div class="about-why-texts">
                                         <img src="img/icon-check.png" />
                                        <div>Automated withdrawal system</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                  
                            </div>
```

Is this the same that you are looking for?

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3t2zkqro/3/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: if `xs` and `sm` are the same width, you only need to specify the smaller one (as it applies to larger sizes unless specified otherwise) - so for less code to write/maintain, you ***only*** need  `class="col-md-4 col-xs-12`

Comment: Huge thanks! It is what I needed. More over, now I understand how it works, and what was the issue, by doing additional reading on BStrap Docs :)

Comment: glad to help you. could you mark the answer so that it can be closed?

Comment: Google says I need more reputation to be able to close it lol .. weird..

Comment: you can check the right symbol and accept the answer.

Comment: WoW I fell so stupid. Where is the right symbol, exactly. I am like litlerally checking everywhere.. =DD Maybe google is right, and I cant do it ATM?

Comment: beside my answer there is digit and up and down arrow. right? so below that down arrow you will be able to find light gray colored check mark symbol.  you can find reference here : http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

It seems you made some mistakes in your html, that do not fit to correct use of bootstrap and it has nothing to do with `text-center`, unless you asked not what you couldn't get.

> Copy the HTML below to begin working with a minimal Bootstrap document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
```

Next you should use bootstrap container to wrap page content:

> Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable.
>
> Use `.container` for a responsive fixed width container.

```
<div class="container">
  ...
</div>
```

> Use `.container-fluid` for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the info! However I have the .container class, its just not included in the code I showed.